# How to do OngoingStubbing for a void method?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock, stubbing

I'm trying to write a unit test that throws exception for a certain number of times before it succeeds. It's doable for method the do not return void:

```
    OngoingStubbing<Result> requestCallStub = when(request.call());

    for(int i = 0; i < numFailures; i++){
        requestCallStub = requestCallStub.thenThrow(
                new Exception("Failing for test reasons, round " + i));
    }
```

However, this is only doable if the call() method is a non-void one. I wonder if there's a way of using the same pattern for a void method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following code:

```
    Stubber deleteStubber = null;
    if (numOfFailures > 0) {
        deleteStubber = PowerMockito.doThrow(new NullPointerException("Testing"));
        for (int i = 1; i < numOfFailures; i++) {
            deleteStubber = deleteStubber.doThrow(new NullPointerException("Testing"));
        }
    }
    deleteStubber.doNothing().when(request).call();
```

Hope it helps others too.